# Shadows in color infrared images lead to distorted NDVI - Correction?

Tags: arcgis-pro, ndvi, shadow

I have a color-infrared raster and I want to calculate the NDVI. The color-infrared comes as RGB (=NIR,R,G) and 8-bit unsigned data type. I'm using ArcGis 2.9.2

In areas of building and tree shadows, the NDVI tends to be 1) distorted, so there is a lot more noise and 2) higher. The picture cutouts below show the difference in NDVI between shadow and non shadow areas. I used a low pass filter (Pic 3), which helped to curb the noise, but the upward distortion still exists.

I tried to mask the shadows by setting a threshold in the NIR, the Red band and the ratio Hue/Intensity [as mentioned here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0924271617302253) But even if I can separate the shadows from the non - shadow areas, I don't know what to do. My first thought was to modify the NDVI-function by adding a value dependent on NIR/Red Value (like: lower values -> higher NDVI correction), but everything I tried until now did not lead to a satisfying result.

**Is there a way to correct the NDVI in shadow areas?**

[image: CIR Image]
[image: NDVI Image]
[image: NDVI + Low Pass Filter]